# Adding new parent item to admin bar

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, admin-bar

I see many questions have been asked about adding something to the admin bar, but still I can't get a new 'parent' admin-bar item for Advanced Custom Fields to work. The admin bar doesn't show up if I add this to my functions.php:

```
function my_theme_admin_bar_render() {
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'parent' => 'Advanced Custom Fields',
    'id' => 'acf',
    'title' => __('Advanced Custom Fields'),
    'href' => admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=acf')
) );
}   
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'my_theme_admin_bar_render' );
```

How can I get this new admin bar item to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll need the `parent` for a root menu item while using [add_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu). But make sure to get the hint in the Codex:

> Note: The Admin Bar is replaced with the toolbar since WordPress
>   Version 3.3. The preferred way to add items to the toolbar is with
>   add_node().

Give it a try:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_acf', 999 );

function toolbar_link_to_acf( $wp_admin_bar ) {
  $args = array(
    'id' => 'acf',
    'title' => 'Advanced Custom Fields',
    'href' => admin_url('edit.php?post_type=acf'),
    'meta' => array('class' => 'toolbar-acf')
  );

  $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
```

Comment: and adding admin_url to the href was the last trick to get it working :) Thx sven, works like a charm!